# Flash Filter XML with as3 using like statement

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, filtering

i want to filter my xml

i want a query like : `select * from product like'% + myword +%'`

i mean for example i want to search in xml all contacts which name contains John

how can i write as3 code to do this?

this is my XML and i want to select XMLList from this list where name contains John.

```
<contacts>  
    <contact>
        <category> category1 </category>
        <name> John Homer </name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <category> category1 </category>
        <name> John Writer </name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <category> category2 </category>
        <name> Joshua Homer </name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <category> category2 </category>
        <name> Alex Homer </name>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

Comment: see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This it the E4X statement to get the "Johns" from your contact list:

```
var johns:XMLList = contacts.contact.(name.toString().indexOf("John") != -1);
```

This will return an XMLList with the contact Elements that contain "John" in their name.
In your sample XML, that are the first two entries.

Edit: I assumed **contacts** is the variable you assigned your xml to, like that:

```
var contacts:XML = <contacts>...</contacts>;
```

Comment: Oh, one little thing that might make this better: contacts.contact.(name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("john") != -1), if you want to be case insensitiv.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the AS3 documentation you'll find enough info to get you started.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html

In your case it would be `yourXml.contact.(name.hasOwnProperty("John"))`. This, however, won't return the list with `John Homer` and `John Writer`. I'm not sure how to use wildcards within your E4X statements.

Comment: did you mean like this : var filteredXml:XMLList = myXml.(name.hasOwnProperty("category1"); 
trace(filteredXml);

Comment: if you post your XML and explain what you're trying to achieve we can help you out more specifically

Comment: i put a xml and it is more clear now i think. but it is very difficult writing code in this site :)

Comment: I adjusted my answer. I'm afraid it's not what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

yourXML.(product.inStr(yourWord) > -1);

For more on E4x (not XPath--that's for AS2), check out http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/